# Bootstrap table rows does not fit headerrow (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a problem using Bootstrap tables in Angular:
My `<td>` tags does not fit the corresponding `<th>` from my tableheader: I am not sure, if it is caused due my calls to the template presenting the `<td>`: 
[image]

Here is my code:

```html
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Students</th>
        <th>Links</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let c of tests">
      <app-preview-container id={{c.id}} name={{c.name}} description={{c.description}} studentCount={{Count[c.id]}}"></app-preview-container>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And thats the component which gets called (`<app-preview-container>`):

```html
<td>
  {{name}}
</td>
<td>
  {{description}}
</td>
<td>
  {{count}}
</td>
<td>
  some buttons
</td>
```

Does anyone has a tip how I can fix that? I have tried a lot using Bootstrap width-params like w-xx or col-md-x or  col-x or using scope="col"/"row". But none of these fixed it.

Comment: can you create stackblitz demo please with demo data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables often look that way when you change `<tr>` / `<td>` display property. HTML tables have their own unique display properties `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;`.

You either have done that or wrapped your `<td>`s with additional div.

You can inspect your table in the console, and check if `<td>`s are direct children of `<tr>` and then set by hand `<tr>` and `<td>` display property to `table-row` and `table-cell`.

An example of a broken table:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

*[style] {
  outline: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Column 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Column 2
    </td>
    <td>
      Column 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr style="display: block;">
      <td>
        Broken
      </td>
      <td>
        Row
      </td>
      <td>
        !
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: inline-block;">
        Broken td
      </td>
      <td>
        !
      </td>
      <td>
        !
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Correct
      </td>
      <td>
        row
      </td>
      <td>
        !
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was, that I wrapped the <td> in the <app-preview...> so <td> where not direct childs of <tr>. like <tr><app-preview-container><td>..</app-preview></tr>